# Wordpress theme footer can't be customized

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I can't customize footer on wordpress "colibri WP" theme or add any widgeds to it nor change copyright text. I tried to change the code in dashborard -> theme editor -> footer.php and this is the code written there:

```
</div><!-- #page -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

All I can do is delete footer completely. Is there a way to change copyright text and add widgets/social media icons to it?

Comment: You can if you know the place of the php file where it is init

Comment: search the file in theme_editor that contain tag <footer>

Answer (score 1):

You can find footer in `template-parts/front-footer/footer.php`. Copyrights are rendered by function called `colibriwp_theme_print_footer_copyright()`

Answer (score 1):

Go to edit footer.php and edit the content:

```
<?php //colibriwp_theme()->get( 'footer' )->render(); ?></div><!-- #page -->
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
    <p>
        TEXT HERE . TEXT HERE. TEXT HERE. TEXT HERE.
    </p>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Save and done.